# Kendo UI grid with angular - curly brackets not binding value in column template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I just started using kendo-ui grid and have created my columns and everything works with data coming back. I tried adding in a template value to my column definitions and the kendo docs say that I should be able to use `{{dataItem.something}}` to access the value in a template. This does NOT work. However doing `<span ng-bind='dataItem.something'></span>` works fine. Why is this, and how can I get the curly braces binding working? Thanks.

Here is a snippet of pseudo code for what I'm doing:

in my html and controller ( I am omitting all the other options like datasources etc..):

```js
this.gridOptions = {
       columns: [ 
        {
          field: 'valueOne',
          template: "<span ng-bind='dataItem.valueOne'></span>" // THIS WORKS
        },
        {
          field: 'valueTwo',
          template: "{{dataItem.valueTwo}}" // THIS DOES NOT WORKS
        }
      ]
    };
```

```html
<div ng-controller="gridController as vm">   
    <div kendo-grid k-options="vm.gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm attempting is right from the kendo documentation and demos:
[http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/the-grid-widget#template‌​s](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/the-grid-widget#templates)
http://dojo.telerik.com/ikEKIr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR;
By removing kendo-angular.js the binding is working as expected.
kendo-angular.js library was still being included in our build and was conflicting with kendo.all.js

More:
The kendo-angular.js library was deprecated and support was moved to kendo professional. The angular functionality was moved into kendo.all.js. The docs are very specific about including libraries in a specific order. The include order must be JQuery, Angular, then Kendo. I checked this and made sure to try the latest versions of all scripts, also tried using the specific versions used in the demos. However after digging a bit further into our scripts it turns out that our build scripts were still including kendo-angular.js farther down the list. Removing this fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use angular templates after app was initialized, when you inserting new HTML angular will ignore it.

Kendo have own templating tags for it:

There are three ways to use the hash syntax:

- Render values as HTML: `#= #`.
- Use HTML encoding to display values: `#:   #`.
- Execute arbitrary JavaScript code: `# if (true) { # ... non-script content here ... # } #.`

Also you can use functions as templates:

```
template:   
    function (e) {
                if (e.type !== 1)
                    return "";
                return '<input type="checkbox"' + (e.canExecute ? 'checked="checked"' : '') + 'disabled="disabled" />';
            }
```

You also can check out [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you take a look at this section of the kendo docs http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/the-grid-widget#templates you can see that in the example (which runs in their dojo) that their column definition uses `  template: "{{ dataItem.ProductName }}"` so why does it work there?

Comment: here is their dojo demo I referred to above http://dojo.telerik.com/ikEKIr